# How to match date mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: sed

Given the following input

```
506028500,1820196768,43,0,84552257, ,1,-71.16,42.42,04/26/2012,
```

I want to filter the date at the end of the row, so I can change its mm/dd/yyyy format into MySQL date format yyyy-mm-dd:

I am trying to match the date at the end of the row having first removed the trailing ',' (comma).

```
{
    s/,$//g
    /\([0-9][0-9]\)\/\([0-9][0-9]\)\/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)$/=
}
```

I'm getting 12847, but am expecting 04262012.

What am I doing wrong, that I can't even match the date that's there?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know that your date will always be at the end of the row?  This would eliminate the need for regexes altogether.

Comment: It's the resulting dump from a database file. It will always be at the end of the row. I want the grouping so I can match and print out the date in a different format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
echo "506028500,1820196768,43,0,84552257, ,1,-71.16,42.42,04/26/2012," | 
sed 's|,\(..\)/\(..\)/\(....\),$|,\3-\2-\1,|'
506028500,1820196768,43,0,84552257, ,1,-71.16,42.42,2012-26-04,
```

If you just want the date:

```
echo "506028500,1820196768,43,0,84552257, ,1,-71.16,42.42,04/26/2012," | 
sed 's|.*,\(..\)/\(..\)/\(....\),$|\3-\2-\1|'
2012-26-04
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
sed "s/\([0-9]\{2\}\)\/\([0-9]\{2\}\)\/\([0-9]\{4\}\)$/\3-\1-\2/g" someFile.txt
```

At least it replaces the date string with one of the desired format.

To only print the date at the end, the following works for me:

```
sed "s/.*\([0-9]\{2\}\)\/\([0-9]\{2\}\)\/\([0-9]\{4\}\)$/\3-\1-\2/g" someFile.txt
```