# remove dates, commas and periods from file names

Tags: linux, rename

I have files with following names, and I want to remove all the dates, periods and commas in the file names

The original file name:

```
Employee Data 8.31.2014 v4.txt  
Hire, Transfer and Termination event 6.30.2013 to 8.31.2014v2.txt  
Expected Work Days 8.31.2014.txt

Employee Data 9.30.2014 v4.txt  
Hire, Transfer, Termination Event 6.30.2013 to 9.30.2014 v2.txt  
Expected Work Days 9.30.2014.txt
```

Here is what I want to achieve:

```
Employee Data.txt  
Hire Transfer Termination Event.txt  
Expected Work Days.txt
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Comment: Take a look at `sed` http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Comment: Why is `v4` removed?

Comment: Your company seriously stores this information in .txt files?

Comment: Surely with the rename Employee Data 8.31.2014 v4.txt will overwrite Employee Data 9.30.2014 v4.txt, or do you want them combining in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you run in a whole bunch of problems with using whitespaces in files, so a one liner will not cut it (find with using exec and sed) at least I donÄt want to figure out all the quoting necessary. So I would recommend to use a small for loop and set the ISF system variable (if not the blanks will interfere). That leads you to something like this:

```
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
```

setting the ISF to breaks (instead of default blanks, read more about it here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/handling-filenames-with-spaces-in-bash.html)

then a small for loop to be able to use sed on each file. Assuming you want to change all files in a folder and it's children use

```
$(find . -name "*.txt")
```

loop over it:

```
for file in $(find . -name "*.txt"); do echo $file; done;
```

now we want to find out about the changing. Commas are quite easy use:

```
for file in $(find . -name "*.txt"); do mv $file $(echo $file | sed -e s/,//); done;
```

for periods, you may want to decide if you want to remove the dates first. For dates you may want to find out if all your dates comply with the format D[D].MM.YYYY. A second problem might that you do not want to remove the dots  before the filetype. I want to point you to  several other questions on the topic of sed and regular expression. 
e.g. here: [How to match date mm/dd/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903595/how-to-match-date-mm-dd-yyyy)